# Converting text to date format YYQQ

Tags: excel

I am storing project start and finish dates in the text format YYQQ. My goal is to convert this text to an actual date format, as to be able to substract finish and start dates to obtain the duration of a project in number of quarters.

For example if a project started in the third quarter of 2015, 15Q3 and finished in the second quarter of 2016, 16Q2, then it took 3 quarters to complete the project.

The excel function DATE requires text to be converted to the format YYMMDD, which is not what I want. Does excel have a function to convert for example text 16Q2 to date YYQQ format?

Comment: Start Date on A1 and Finish Date on B1. And here is the formula: `=(VALUE(LEFT(B1,2))-VALUE(LEFT(A1,2)))*4+(VALUE(RIGHT(B1,1))‌​-VALUE(RIGHT(A1,1)))‌​& " Quarters"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel does not have that function.  But you can easily write a formula to do that conversion:

To convert to a normal excel date:

```
=DATE(LEFT(Start,2)+2000,(RIGHT(Start,1)-1)*3,1)
```

will return the starting date of the quarter.

For a date close to the middle of the quarter, something like:

```
=DATE(LEFT(Start,2)+2000,(RIGHT(Start,1)-1)*3,45)
```